# Duplicating data in crystal report with MySQL and C#

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

I have a problem in displaying the data in crystal report using left join. When i use "where no_barang = 2" in Phpmyadmin is working. But in crystalreport not working (the data is duplicate, and showing all data).

table "barang"

```
no_barang   | nama_barang   | harga_barang  
1           | sepatu        | 25000 
2           | baju          | 47000
```

table "pelanggan"

```
no_pelanggan    | nama_pelanggan        
1               | Sugeng Agung Suganda
2               | Babay Azifahmi
```

table "pembelian"

```
no_order    | no_pelanggan  | no_barang | jumlah    
1           |       1       |    2      |   2   
2           |       2       |    1      |   1
```

This my code in crystalreport

```
MySqlParameter p;
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("database=cs_reportmultitables;server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=");

public View(string sTitle)
{
InitializeComponent();
try
{
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string query;
p = new MySqlParameter("@no_order", MySqlDbType.String);
p.Value = sTitle;
query = "SELECT pembelian.no_order, pelanggan.nama_pelanggan, barang.nama_barang, barang.harga_barang, pembelian.jumlah FROM pembelian LEFT JOIN pelanggan ON pembelian.no_pelanggan = pelanggan.no_pelanggan LEFT JOIN barang ON pembelian.no_barang = barang.no_barang WHERE no_order=@no_order";
MySqlDataAdapter dscmd = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
dscmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(p);
dscmd.Fill(ds);
RPT cryds = new RPT();
cryds.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryds;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
conn.Close();
}
conn.Close();
}
```

Trying to display number 2 and my output was this:

```
no_order | nama_pelanggan       | nama_barang | harga_barang | jumlah
1        | Sugeng Agung Suganda | sepatu      | 25000        | 2
2        | Babay Azifahmi       | sepatu      | 25000        | 1
```

It duplicate in "nama_barang" and "harga_barang", should display data like this:

```
2        | Babay Azifahmi       | sepatu      | 25000        | 1
```

Please help me if anyone know?

Comment: There is absolutely no need/relation to the fact that you have a DataGridView , or did I miss something ? I suggest you to remove that section in your question for sake of clarity

Comment: @sandwood thank you for feedback, my question is improved. Can you help me?